# PIP: Requirement already satisfied: imutils

Tags: opencv, pip

I am trying to run a home surveillance program using rasp pi 3 model b
i have done: 
`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-opencv` successfully but somehow stuck below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/pi-home-surveillance# python pi_surveillance.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pi_surveillance.py", line 13, in <module>
    import imutils
ImportError: No module named imutils
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/pi-home-surveillance# pip install imutils
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

I have tried reinstalling everything related but to no effect

PS: pip3 was also tried (irrelevant)

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/pi-home-surveillance# pip3 install imutils
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imutils library per the [github page](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) is written for "both Python 2.7 and Python 3" so you can copy the file(s) from `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Try not use `sudo`, just type `sudo pip install imutils`.

I solved this problem using that command

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

pip install --upgrade imutils

Comment: OP already said that they have tried that command but get an error.